# Looking To Extract A Substring

Tags: python, substring

I am looking for a way to extract a substring/ many substrings from a piece of text.

I need to be able to extract the #Covid19 and #VaccineRecovery from the string below.

> Significant milestone today. First day with no reported #CoVid19
> deaths since March 21st. This is a day of hope. We will prevail #VaccineRecovery.

Basically I need any substring that starts with "#" up until the next blank space. There might be 1 or more than 1 hash tags to extract from each sentence.

Comment: If you'd like to tag a Python question, please include the Python code you've tried so far

Comment: And you did code exactly what to get there? [mre]? what is the problem with the solution you cooked up?

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, suggestions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Can you please show the work you have done so far?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

the below seems to do the job. split the string into words and check which word starts with `#`

```
data = 'Significant milestone today. First day with no reported #CoVid19 deaths since March 21st. This is a day of hope. We will prevail #VaccineRecovery.'
words = [x for x in data.split() if x and x[0] == '#']
print(words)
```

output

```
['#CoVid19', '#VaccineRecovery.']
```

Comment: I'd suggest using `startswith` to avoid problems with empty strings

Comment: The OP has not attempted or shown any work; this is against SO guidelines afaik.

Comment: Any reason  for  down vote?

Comment: the answer is right, but the question is badly designed. therefore we should not encourage it.

Comment: @rv.kvetch so down vote the question - not the answer.